# how to pass image from listview item to a dialog box WITHOUT the use of an intent

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an activity and custom dialog. the activity has two textview and 1 image view. the dialog box has a textview and an imageview. when a user clicks the item in the listview the dialog box shows. i am trying to get the imageview from the activity to show in the dialog box's imageview. With some help, i got the textview from the activity to the dialog box. but i am having problems passing the image as well.

My custom dialog:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
 // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
 // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    //builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogb, null));
    View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogb, null);
    TextView dialogt = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
    ImageView dialogImg = (ImageView)content.findViewById(R.id.dialog_pic);
    dialogImg.setId(getArguments().getInt("id"));
    dialogt.setText(getArguments().getCharSequence("text"));
    builder.setView(content);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_Event)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.add_to_cal, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   Toast.makeText(MyDialogFragment.this.getActivity(), "testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it

    return builder.create();
}
}
```

in my activity i use this method:

```
public void confirmEvent(CharSequence text, int id) {
        DialogFragment mDialog = new MyDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putCharSequence("text", text);
        args.getInt("id", id);

        mDialog.setArguments(args);
        mDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");
    }
```

this is my onItemclick :

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                //String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                int img = ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.event_pic)).getId();
                String txt =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.subTitle_single)).getText().toString();

                //Toast.makeText(Homepage.this,img , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                confirmEvent(txt, img);
            }
```

I really i didnt want to use Intents for this, but if that is the only way please let me know the best way to implement.

**/////EDITED///**

after changing to dialogImage.setImageResource ( as suggested in comments)

```
 View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogb, null);
    TextView dialogt = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
    ImageView dialogImg = (ImageView)content.findViewById(R.id.dialog_pic);
    //dialogImg.setImageResource(getArguments().getImageResource(R.id.event_pic));
    dialogImg.setImageResource(getArguments().getInt("id"));
    //ImageView dialogImg2 = (ImageView)dialogt
    dialogt.setText(getArguments().getCharSequence("text"));
    builder.setView(content);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_Event)
```

my onitemclick:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                //String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                int img = ((ImageView)view.getTag(R.id.event_pic)).getId();
                String txt =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.subTitle_single)).getText().toString();

                //Toast.makeText(Homepage.this,img , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                confirmEvent(txt, img);
```

it now crashes when i click an item. if i am missing the image position, how do i put it into the code?

Comment: In your activity you have the ImageView called event_pic. Is the image in this view changing dynamically, or is it always the same?

Comment: Well it is being pulled remotely by a Jason parser. The image is different depending on which list view item is clicked.

Comment: As a suggestion, cann't you pass the selected image location rather than passing the image ?

Comment: Can you create a static class that will hold your JSON object? That way you can use the information in all your class (something like a DBHelper class)?

Comment: Check answer in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863714/how-to-put-image-in-a-bundle-and-pass-it-to-another-activity). You might need to use it along with `ImageView.getDrawingCache()` function.

Comment: It does not have to be the image itself that is passed. If I could get a reference to the image I know it would be much more efficient. Also so not worry about the Jason side of it. That is already taken care of

Comment: @Zusee Weekin I wuld prefer that but I'm not sure how to go about doing that, any suggestions?

Comment: What is the source of the image in your `ImageView`? Is it a `Bitmap` or a `File`? In either case, you will need to pass the source on the the `DialogFragment` and set up it's `ImageView` in the same way as done in your `ListAdapter`. There is no point in passing on the id of the `ImageView` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Set the image location to the list item by setTag() method and in onItemClick method use view.getTag() method to get the location

Edited : In MyDialogFragment class you have to set the image resource. You have set only image id which won't work.
Use diaolgImage.setImageResource('id of image /drawable of the image ')

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Should I leave the get Id() at the end of were I declare int IMG in onitem click?

Comment: also, are there any changes i need to make in the custom dialog?

Comment: This thing is still confusing me. OK, i have the listview item image file path and position stored in a hashmap named hmBitmap. using that information how do i pass the listview item image "imageView" to the itemView of the dialog box????? without using any intent. ( and i dont mean the actual image. i just want to see the image in the imageView)

Comment: Did you try diaolgImage.setImageResource('id of image /drawable of the image ') ?

Comment: i cannot try that method because i do not know the correct syntax to put the id in.( i cannot just say R.id.event_pic because i am not inflating that in the dialog box, i am inflating it in the activity), thats y i want to know how to use the data i already have in the hashmap, but i dunno the correct way to do it. and why are we using drawable? i read that u cannot pass a drawable unless ur using parcels or something like that.

Comment: i have edited my code, see above. it crashes when i click on the item. If i am missing to add the position, how do i put it in?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the image location, within onItemClick() method save the image path in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

```
SharedPreferences shared=getSharedPreferences("app_name", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
shared.edit().putString("image_path", "path").commit();
```

Inside your dialog window you can retrieve it,

```
SharedPreferences shared=getSharedPreferences("app_name", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String path=shared.getString("image_path", null);
```

Or else you can save it in **cache**,But beware when the device is low on internal storage space, Android may delete these cache files to recover space.